# Adding vectors by index in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset like this:

```
id | house_id | room_data
-------------------------------------------
1  | abc      | [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2  | abc      | [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3  | abc      | [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0]
4  | abc      | [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
5  | def      | [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
6  | def      | NULL
7  | def      | [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
8  | def      | [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I would like to select the vectors associated with a given `house_id` and create a new aggregate vector which sums up each corresponding vector by its `index`

An example result for a query with `house_id` of `abc` would ideally look like this:

```
house_id | aggregate_room_data
--------------------------------
abc      | [3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2]
```

And an example result for a query with `house_id` of `def`:

```
house_id | aggregate_room_data
--------------------------------------
def      | [3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

I believe I need some combination of `ARRAY_AGG`, `CROSS JOIN UNNEST`, `SUM` and maybe `WITH OFFSET` but I'm a dummy and just can't get the syntax right, even though I think I'm circling the answer here.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: what is data type of `room_data` column? is it array of ints or string?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant it is an array of ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select house_id, 
  array_agg(data order by offset) as aggregate_room_data
from (
  select house_id, offset, sum(data) data
  from `project.dataset.table`, 
  unnest(room_data) data with offset 
  where not room_data is null
  group by house_id, offset
)
group by house_id
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]